# Problema String Consulta MySQL a PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo problemas para ingresar esta consulta SQL a mi código PHP necesito ayuda para implementarlo.
Desde ya, agradezco las respuestas

```
SELECT id, `name`, lnk, img, tabla FROM
(SELECT id, `name`, lnk, img, "Channels" as tabla FROM channels
UNION ALL   
SELECT id, `name`, lnk, img, "Series" AS tabla FROM series
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, `name`, lnk, img, "Tvpg" AS tabla FROM tvpg
) AS todas
WHERE `name` LIKE "%$busqueda"
```

> 

ERROR:
Fatal error
: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs----\sch.php:61 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp\htdocs----\sch.php
on line
61

```
    <?php 
if (isset($_GET['buscar'])) {
    $busqueda = $_GET['busqueda'];

    $call = $connect->query("AQUI VA LA CONSULTA");
}

    if(isset($call)){
    while ($row = $call->fetch_array()) {

        ?>

        <div class="result">
            <a href="<?php echo $row['lnk']?>"><img class="" src="<?php echo $row['img']?>" alt=""></a>
            <p class="titleResult"><?php echo $row['name']?></p>
            
        </div>
<?php 

    }
}
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Prueba con `LIKE "%%$busqueda"`

Comment: Esta consulta debería ser errónea desde el punto de vista sintáctico. ¿La has probado en el SGBD directamente? ¿Funciona?

Answer (score 1):

Los errores del tipo: *`Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool`* suelen ocurrir cuando la consulta SQL falla, sea por errores en la misma consulta o en la conexión.

Si estableces los controles adecuados en tu código podrás saber lo que ocurre, pudiendo así poner en práctica un aspecto muy importante si quieres escribir un programa robusto: **el manejo adecuado de errores**.

Veamos un ejemplo donde se controla en todo momento el flujo del código. Aquí usaremos una variable `$outPut` en forma de array, poniendo en la misma una clave `error` cuando éstos ocurraran.

```
<?php 
    /*
        Si tienes PHP inferior a la versión 7
        cambia esta línea por:
        $busqueda=!empty($_GET['buscar']) ? $_GET['buscar'] : NULL;
    */           
    $busqueda=$_GET['buscar'] ?? NULL;
    $outPut=array();
    
    if ($busqueda) {
        if($connect) {
            $sql="AQUI VA LA CONSULTA";
            if ( $call = $connect->query($sql) ) {
                $mData=array();
                while ( $row = $call->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    $mData[]=$row;
                }
                if ($mData) {
                    $html="<div class=\"result\">";
                    foreach ($mData as $row) {
                        $html.="<a href=\"$row[lnk]\"><img class=\"\" src=\"$row[img]\" alt=\"\"></a>";
                        $html.="<p class=\"titleResult\">$row[name]</p>";
                    }
                    $html.="</div>";
                    $outPut['data']=$html;
                } else {
                    $outPut['error']='No se encontraron datos';
                }
            } else {
                /*
                   En producción cambia $connect->error
                   por un mensaje de error personalizado
                   aquí lo ponemos para conocer con exactitud el error
                */
                $outPut['error']=sprintf('Error SQL: %s',$connect->error);
            }
        } else {
            $outPut['error']='No hay conexión';
        }
    } else {
        $outPut['error']='No se enviaron criterios de búsqueda';
    }
    
    /*
       Aquí mostraremos 'error'  o 'data'
       según lo que haya ocurrido en el flujo del código
       Si tu PHP es inferior a la versión 7
       debes cambiar esta línea por esto:
       echo isset($outPut['error']) ? $outPut['error'] : $outPut['data'];
       O bien usar un if tradicional
    */

    echo $outPut['error'] ?? $outPut['data'];
?>
```

**POST-DATA**:

Algún programador ingenuo podría quejarse de que es un código demasiado largo y con muchos `if`. Si tú quieres escribir un código robusto, deberás evaluar de algún modo **todo aquello que podría fallar** y salir al frente de esos fallos, sea informando al usuario o de otro modo, según el propósito del programa que estés escribiendo. En este código tú sabrás siempre lo que ha ocurrido, y si ha fallado, sabrás que ha fallado y podrás mostrar un mensaje o decidir otra acción o lo que sea.